# reading inputs in python and going to the next line if some error happens

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a coding problem and basically, I am organizing the following data into a list.

```
1-3 a: abcde
1-3 b: cdefg
2-9 c: ccccccccc
```

How do I read only the first three characters of each line and store strictly those in a list? I just want the numbers 1 and 3 for example then skip the rest of the line and move to the next line and do the same. Since it is a mix of integers and words, doing int(input()) just throws an error when the compiler gets to the non-integer part like "-" or ":"

Comment: anyone other way to just organize the data into a list would also be appreciated!

Comment: Is the data in a file or are you typing at the input prompt?

Comment: not a file, just copy pasting it, so yes basically typing it in the prompt

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing is to take the input as string and then do string manipulation:

```
s = input("Enter the string") 
res = []
t = s.split(" ")[0].split("-")
res.extend(list(map(int,t)))
```

If you want add multiple inputs, you can move the logic into a while loop and continue for n no of times:

```
In [5]: def extract_num(s,res=[]): 
   ...:     t = s.split(" ")[0].split("-") 
   ...:     res.extend(list(map(int,t))) 

In [13]: def extract_numbers(): 
    ...:     res = [] 
    ...:     while True: 
    ...:         user_input = input("Enter the string ") 
    ...:         extract_num(user_input,res) 
    ...:         answer =input("Do you want to continue,yes or no") 
    ...:         if answer.lower() != "yes": 
    ...:             break 
    ...:     print(res) 
    ...:                                                                                     

In [14]: extract_numbers()                                                                   
Enter the string 1-3 a: abcde
Do you want to continue,yes or noYes
Enter the string 1-3 a: abcde
Do you want to continue,yes or nono
[1, 3, 1, 3]
```

this is based on assumption that all inputs would be of same format.

Comment: this works, but i need it to do this for the next two lines as well.

Comment: it would be perfect if this would work for the next line of input data, but the s variable only accepts strings and those aren't read line by line by the compiler like integers are

Comment: is the input entered by command line or read from a file?

Comment: the input data is 200 lines long lol. here it is: https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/2/input

Answer (score 1):

The data is stored at "data.txt":

```
1-3 a: abcde
1-3 b: cdefg
2-9 c: ccccccccc
```

I will use a regular expression, just to extract the integers at the beginning of the line:

```
import re

file = open('data.txt', 'r') 
data = []

for line in file: 
    x = re.findall("^(\d+)-(\d+)", line)
    data.append(x[0]) 

file.close
```

`data` has the following values: `[('1', '3'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '9')]`

Comment: i havent done much data handling but I will try this! so there isn't a way to go to the next line of input data?